# Retrieve length of slice from slice object in Python

Tags: python, list, slice

The title explains itself, how to get 2 out of the object

```
slice(0,2)
```

The documentation is somewhat confusing, or it is the wrong one

https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/slice.html

In particular I don't understand what is the meaning of the output of

```
slice(0,2).indices(0)  # (0, 0, 1)
slice(0,2).indices(10 ** 10)  # (0, 2, 1)
```

One possible workaround is to slice a list with the slice object

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
len(a[slice(0,2)])  # 2
```

But this will fail for an arbitrary large slice.

Thanks, I couldn't find an answer In other posts.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no complete answer for this. `slice` doesn't give you a length because the length of the result is always dependent on the size of the sequence being sliced, a short sequence (including an empty sequence) will produce fewer items, and if the `slice` is unbounded, then the length will grow in tandem with the length of the sequence; a `slice` might just go "to end of sequence" by having a `start` or `stop` of `None`.

For a quick and easy way to compute the length for a sequence of a known length, you just combine `.indices` with Py3's `range` (or `xrange` in Py2, though `xrange` has limitations on values that Py3 `range` does not). [`slice.indices` gives you the concrete `start`, `stop` and `stride` values derived when a `slice` applies to a sequence of a given length](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slice.indices), it's basically the values you'd fill in in a C-style `for` loop that traverses the same indices as the `slice`:

```c
for (ssize_t i = start; i < stop; i += stride)
```

So to calculate the length of a `slice` when applied to a sequence with 1000 elements, you'd do:

```
>>> len(range(*slice(0, 2).indices(1000)))
2
>>> len(range(*slice(10, None, 3).indices(1000)))
330
```

If you're on Python 2, and your values might exceed what `xrange` can handle (it's limited to bounds and total length equal to what a `ssize_t` can hold), you can just do the calculation by hand:

```
def slice_len_for(slc, seqlen):
    start, stop, step = slc.indices(seqlen)
    return max(0, (stop - start + (step - (1 if step > 0 else -1))) // step)

>>> slice_len_for(slice(10, None, 3), 1000)
330
```

**Update:** Unfortunately, `slice.indices` itself won't accept a `len` for the sequence beyond what a `long` can hold, so this doesn't gain you anything over using `xrange` in Py2. Left in place for those interested, but the workaround doesn't workaround anything unless you also [perform the work `slice` does to convert negative values and `None` to concrete values based on the sequence length.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/sliceobject.c#L102) Sigh.

Answer (score 7):

So it looks like `slice.indices(n)` returns the arguments to be given to `range`, to get the item indices which should be reflected in the slice of a sequence of length `n` (<s>although it's not documented</s> **edit:** as @ShadowRanger pointed out, it is indeed [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slice.indices)). So the following lines evaluate to the same values:

```
# get some list to work on
my_list = list(range(100))

# slice syntax
print(my_list[1:15:3])
# regular item access
print(my_list[slice(1,15,3)])
# reinvent list slicing
print([my_list[i] for i in range(*slice(1,15,3).indices(len(my_list)))])
```

As you see, the resulting list's length is the same as the length of `range(*slice(1,15,3).indices(len(my_list)))`, which depends on the `slice` object itself, and the length of the sequence to be sliced. That's why `len(range(*slice.indices(n)))` will give you the right answer in Python 3. (the range object is a generator, which fortunately has the `__len__` function defined, so it can give you the item count, without the need to enumerate and count them.)

If you work with large numbers in python 2, you can replicate the calculation as @ShadowRanger suggests.

The original implementation of `range.__len__` is the following:

```c
/* Return number of items in range (lo, hi, step).  step != 0
 * required.  The result always fits in an unsigned long.
 */
static unsigned long
get_len_of_range(long lo, long hi, long step)
{
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------
    If step > 0 and lo >= hi, or step < 0 and lo <= hi, the range is empty.
    Else for step > 0, if n values are in the range, the last one is
    lo + (n-1)*step, which must be <= hi-1.  Rearranging,
    n <= (hi - lo - 1)/step + 1, so taking the floor of the RHS gives
    the proper value.  Since lo < hi in this case, hi-lo-1 >= 0, so
    the RHS is non-negative and so truncation is the same as the
    floor.  Letting M be the largest positive long, the worst case
    for the RHS numerator is hi=M, lo=-M-1, and then
    hi-lo-1 = M-(-M-1)-1 = 2*M.  Therefore unsigned long has enough
    precision to compute the RHS exactly.  The analysis for step < 0
    is similar.
    ---------------------------------------------------------------*/
    assert(step != 0);
    if (step > 0 && lo < hi)
    return 1UL + (hi - 1UL - lo) / step;
    else if (step < 0 && lo > hi)
    return 1UL + (lo - 1UL - hi) / (0UL - step);
    else
    return 0UL;
}
```

And `slice.indices`:

```c
int
PySlice_GetIndices(PySliceObject *r, Py_ssize_t length,
                   Py_ssize_t *start, Py_ssize_t *stop, Py_ssize_t *step)
{
    /* XXX support long ints */
    if (r->step == Py_None) {
        *step = 1;
    } else {
        if (!PyInt_Check(r->step) && !PyLong_Check(r->step)) return -1;
        *step = PyInt_AsSsize_t(r->step);
    }
    if (r->start == Py_None) {
        *start = *step < 0 ? length-1 : 0;
    } else {
        if (!PyInt_Check(r->start) && !PyLong_Check(r->step)) return -1;
        *start = PyInt_AsSsize_t(r->start);
        if (*start < 0) *start += length;
    }
    if (r->stop == Py_None) {
        *stop = *step < 0 ? -1 : length;
    } else {
        if (!PyInt_Check(r->stop) && !PyLong_Check(r->step)) return -1;
        *stop = PyInt_AsSsize_t(r->stop);
        if (*stop < 0) *stop += length;
    }
    if (*stop > length) return -1;
    if (*start >= length) return -1;
    if (*step == 0) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

The sources are from [svn](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/)

Comment: FYI, [`slice.indices` is documented, just not in the place you'd expect.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slice.indices). The docstring in the interactive interpreter is also useful.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Woah, you are right on this one too! I didn't manage to find that. (I updated my answer with that information if you dont mind)

Comment: Additional note (sorry for necromancy): "the range object is a generator, which fortunately has the `__len__` function defined" is wrong. It's not a generator, it's actually a complete sequence type (it was slightly incomplete before 3.2, but fulfills the `Sequence` ABC as of 3.2, which was the same time it added support for arbitrarily large values). You can index it, slice it, iterate it forward or backwards multiple times, call `.index` or `.count` on it just like a `list`, etc. It's low overhead (it doesn't *store* any of the numbers, generating them on demand), but it's not a iterator.

Answer (score 2):

## If the sequence's *length* is known

ShadowRanger's answer covered the generic solution, but if (like me) you **do** know the length of the sequence - here's a simple approach that should handle it like `range` would (including most edge cases), and without iteration over potentially long sequences.

This is similar to what Markus wrote but handles more edge cases.

```
from math import ceil

def max_slice_len(s: slice):
    assert s.stop or s.stop == 0, "Must define stop for max slice len!"
    assert s.step != 0, "Step slice cannot be zero"
    
    start = s.start or 0
    stop = s.stop
    step = s.step or 1
    
    delta = (stop - start)
    dsteps = int(ceil(delta / step))
    
    return dsteps if dsteps >= 0 else 0

def slice_len(s: slice, src_len: int):
    stop = min(s.stop, src_len)
    return max_slice_len(slice(s.start, stop, s.step))
```

**Explanation:**
Assuming we can get the "max length" of a slice without some `src_len`,
we can then build on that by taking the `src_len` (the length of the list or whatever you want to iterate over) as the `stop` of the slice if it's smaller than the current `stop`.

But that still leaves the problem of finding the "max length".

---

## Getting the max length of a slice

The slice construct in python creates a sort of [Arithmetic Set](https://www.chilimath.com/lessons/intermediate-algebra/arithmetic-sequence-definition-and-basic-examples/). 
where `a0` == `start`, `d` == `step`, `n` == `len`

a formula tells us: `a_n = a0+ (n-1)d` 
[`a_n` is the nth element of the sequence] 
if we treat `stop` as `a_n`then: `stop = start + (len - 1) * step`. 
rearranging we get: `len = [(stop-start)/step] + 1`.

This nicely takes care of reverse iteration for us just as easily(ie. [10:0:-1]),

But it will usually return a float, as stop might not be a full number of "steps" beyond start. (i.e for [0:10:3], (10-0) / 3 gives us 3.3333...). 
using `ceil` fixes that.

The only issue remaining is negative results ([10:0:1] will give us (0-10)/1 = -10), but the actual "length" should be zero. 
The solution is to cut off negative results by returning `dsteps if dsteps >= 0 else 0`

---

## Tests

```
import unittest
# import max_slice_len, slice_len

class TestSliceUtil(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_max_len_suite(self):
        simple_test_cases = [
            (slice(0, 10, 1), 10),
            (slice(0, 10, 2), 5),
            (slice(0, 10, 3), 4),
            (slice(0, 10, 10), 1),
            (slice(0, 10, 100), 1),
            (slice(-1, 10, 5), 3),
            (slice(-10, -1, 3), 3),
            (slice(15, 10, 1), 0),
            (slice(0, 10, -1), 0),
            (slice(0, 10, -3), 0),
            (slice(15, 10, -1), 5),
            (slice(10, 0, -1), 10),

            # none replacement (without len)
            (slice(None, 10, 1), 10),
            (slice(0, 10, None), 10),
        ]

        def test_len(s: slice, expected_len: int):
            iter_len = s.stop + 1  # simulate some iterable that is longer than the max_len

            enumerated_idxs = list(range(s.start or 0, s.stop, s.step or 1))
            enumerated_len = len(enumerated_idxs)

            result = slice_len(s, iter_len)
            self.assertEqual(result, expected_len, "Not same as expected!")
            self.assertEqual(result, enumerated_len, "Not same as enumerated!")

        def test_max_len(s: slice, expected_len: int):
            result = max_slice_len(s)
            self.assertEqual(result, expected_len,
                             "Max len was not equal! slice: {}. expected: {}. Actual: {}".format(s, expected_len,
                                                                                                 result))
        for case in simple_test_cases:
            s, expected = case
            with self.subTest("max_len {} -> {}".format(s, expected)):
                test_max_len(s, expected)
            with self.subTest("len vs enumerated {} -> {}".format(s, expected)):
                test_len(s, expected)
```

Answer (score 1):

### The best way to do this is to turn the slice into a range.

A range will have all the functionality you'd need.

---

```
def SliceToRange(slc: slice) -> range:
    """Function for Converting a Slice to a Range"""
    DefaultTo = lambda value, default: value if value is not None else default
    return range(DefaultTo(slc.start, 0), slc.stop, DefaultTo(slc.step, 1))
```

A slice is basically just a `namedtuple` with the same attributes as a range. What's happening here is you're just transferring the values of the slice to a range object.

The problem is that most of the time, slices have `None`s as their values, which ranges won't accept. I fixed this by adding the `DefaultTo` lambda, which replaces `None` with the default value given, and putting the respective defaults for start and step.

There is also the problem that slice doesn't have any type checking, so you can do something like `slice("dfa", True)` or `["hello": type]`, and it wouldn't care. But you're probably not going to encounter that very often. If you do, the range won't accept it and will raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

## a simplified approach with asserts

The length depends on the target object, which is sliced.
But one can define a *maximum length*.

**Example**

define your maximum length function like this

```
def slice_len_max(s):
    assert (s.start is not None)
    assert (s.stop is not None)
    step = 1
    if s.step is not None:
        step = s.step
    return max((s.stop - s.start) // step, 1)
```

and check the output

```
>>> slice_len_max(slice(0, 10))
10
>>> slice_len_max(slice(0, 10, 2))
5
>>> slice_len_max(slice(0, 10, 3))
3
>>> slice_len_max(slice(0, 10, 10))
1
>>> slice_len_max(slice(0, 10, 100))
1
>>> slice_len_max(slice(3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in slice_len_max
AssertionError
```

The last call crashes, as the slice has no `start` attribute defined.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is:

```
>>> s = slice(0,2)
>>> len(range(s.stop)[s])
2
```

Answer (score 0):

If U know the size of the list/tuple you can use:

```
def slice_length(s: slice, seq_length: int):
    """Returns the seq_length of the slice"""
    start, stop, step = s.indices(seq_length)
    # replace None values and negative start/stop values
    delta = stop - start
    if step == 1:
        return delta
    steps = int(ceil(delta / step))
    return max(0, steps)
```

To test the function you can use unittest:

```
def possible_non_empty_slices_iterator(length: int) -> Iterator[slice]:
    """Returns an iterator of all possible slices of a list of seq_length"""
    for step in range(-length, length):
        if step != 0:
            for start in range(-length, length):
                for stop in range(-length, length):
                    curr_slice = slice(start, stop, step)
                    if slice_length(curr_slice, length) > 0:
                        yield curr_slice

class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    lists = [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        [],
        [1],
        [1, 2],
        ["dwfbb", [12e1], {"my key"}, {"my key": "my value"}]
    ]

    def test_slice_length(self):
        for example in self.lists:
            for curr_slice in possible_non_empty_slices_iterator(len(example)):
                with self.subTest(example=example, _slice=curr_slice):
                    computed_slice_length = slice_length(curr_slice, len(example))
                    wanted_slice_length = len(example[curr_slice])
                    self.assertEqual(computed_slice_length, wanted_slice_length)
```

Answer (score -5):

```
>>> slice(0,2).__getattribute__('stop')
2
>>> slice(0,2).__getattribute__('start')
0
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer].

Comment: This is wrong - `stop` and `start` don't give you the length - it depends on the `step` _and_ on the length of the item you're slicing.  And if you want to get `stop` and `start` attributes, why use `__getattribute__`?  Why not just say, `slice(2).start`?