# What is the point of the slice.indices method?

Tags: python, range, slice

What is the point of the [`slice.indices`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slice.indices) method, since we have the following equality?

```py
s = slice(start, stop, step)
assert range(*s.indices(length)) == range(length)[s]
```

Comment: Yes, if all you're going to do with the result of `.indices()` is pass it all to `range()`, it's pointless.  But what if you wanted to do something with the individual values - determine the `step` of an existing slice, for example?

Comment: @jasonharper You can already get the individual values of `s.indices(length)` with `range(length)[s].start`, `range(length)[s].stop`, and `range(length)[s].step`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `slice.indices` method is now useless because `s.indices(length)` is equal to `(range(length)[s].start, range(length)[s].stop, range(length)[s].step)`, but it is kept for backwards compatibility. Slicing support was added to `range` in [Python 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#other-language-changes) so the `slice.indices` method was only useful in previous Python versions:

> `range` objects now support *index* and *count* methods. This is part of an effort to make more objects fully implement the `collections.Sequence` abstract base class. As a result, the language will have a more uniform API. In addition, `range` objects now support slicing and negative indices, even with values larger than `sys.maxsize`. This makes range more interoperable with lists:
>
> ```
> >>> range(0, 100, 2).count(10)
> 1
> >>> range(0, 100, 2).index(10)
> 5
> >>> range(0, 100, 2)[5]
> 10
> >>> range(0, 100, 2)[0:5]
> range(0, 10, 2)
> ```
>
> (Contributed by Daniel Stutzbach in bpo-9213, by Alexander Belopolsky
> in bpo-2690, and by Nick Coghlan in bpo-10889.)

The credit goes to [Karl Knechtel](https://discuss.python.org/t/what-is-the-point-of-the-slice-indices-method/30077/2?u=maggyero).

Comment: Hmm, so it was only ever useful in `range(*...)`? Nobody ever used it for anything else? How do you know?

Comment: @KellyBundy Because you can already get the individual values of `s.indices(length)` with `range(length)[s].start`, `range(length)[s].stop`, and `range(length)[s].step`.

Comment: That's more code, though.

Comment: @KellyBundy: I doubt it has seen much use outside `range(*...)` ([that's what I've used it for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36188683/364696)), but if someone did use it for something else, it's not like they're taking it away (most code supporting `.indices` is needed in other contexts, so the incremental maintenance burden is small). If they ever removed it, `indices = operator.attrgetter('start', 'stop', 'step')` could be used to enable a one-line replacement `indices(range(length)[s])`, but they're not removing it, and it's almost never used otherwise, so that's unlikely to be needed.