# Get indexes chosen when slicing a list

Tags: python, slice

I have a list:

```py
things = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

I also have a slice object provided to me, intended for the list above. Here's an example:

```py
s = slice(-2, None, None)
print(things[-2:])  # ['e', 'f']
```

My goal is to extract the specific indexes the slice impacts. In this example, that would be:

```py
[4, 5]
```

Does anyone know how I would go about doing this more pythonically? My current solution is:

```py
print([i for i in range(len(things))][s])  # [4, 5]
```

Comment: I fixed the assignment to `s` such that using it would actually give the corresponding result. `slice(-2, 0, None)` does not work; it would be equivalent to attempting `things[-2:0]`, which gives an empty result.

Comment: Maybe `list(range(len(things))][s])`?

Comment: This wouldn't work for an example where the slice object has a step.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter as far as I can tell it works just fine, and so do all my suggestions.

Comment: Related (answer almost identical, but question has completely different focus): [Retrieve length of slice from slice object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36188429/364696)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the purpose of the `indices` method of the `slice` class.

As explained in the built-in help:

```
Help on built-in function indices:

indices(...) method of builtins.slice instance
    S.indices(len) -> (start, stop, stride)
    
    Assuming a sequence of length len, calculate the start and stop
    indices, and the stride length of the extended slice described by
    S. Out of bounds indices are clipped in a manner consistent with the
    handling of normal slices.
```

Thus, pass it the length of the sequence that will be sliced, in order to get the corresponding start/stop/stride values:

```
>>> s = slice(-2, None, None)
>>> 
>>> things = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> things[s]
['e', 'f']
>>> s.indices(len(things))
(4, 6, 1)
>>> x, y, z = s.indices(len(things))
>>> things[x:y:z]
['e', 'f']
```

Which can of course be used to construct the corresponding `range` of values:

```
>>> list(range(*s.indices(len(things))))
[4, 5]
```

As an aside, `range` objects can be indexed and sliced directly, and converting them to lists is as easy as passing them directly to the `list` type. Thus:

```
>>> list(range(len(things))[s])
[4, 5]
>>> list(range(len(things)))[s]
[4, 5]
```

This is simpler for getting an actual list of indices; in other contexts (for example, implementing `__getitem__` for a custom type) the start/stop/stride values may be more directly useful.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `list(range(len(things))[s])` is much more efficient than `list(range(len(things)))[s]` when the size of the slice is much smaller than the size of the input list.

Comment: The `indices` method isn't actually helpful here and your "aside" is the actual answer...

Comment: For the output format that was requested, sure; but people often request the wrong output because they simply haven't considered the possibilities.

Comment: Even if that's the case (and I doubt it), I'd say you still have it backwards. The question is what it is, and it's reasonable. I think your current "aside" should come first, and the `indices` method can be an aside following it.